# Как получить имя формы с которой были отправлены данные?

Tags: php, html, css

```
  <form class='item-card' name='first' action='reload.php' method = 'post' enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>
  </form>
  <form class='item-card' name='second' action='reload.php' method = 'post' enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>
  </form>
```

На сайте есть много форм, и мне нужно получить name формы с которой были отправлены данные, и передать name в селектор.Форм очень много и их name генерируется рандомно. Как это сделать?

```
<style> form[name=first]{ display: none; } </style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<form class='item-card' name='first' action='reload.php' method = 'post' enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>
  <input type="hidden" name="formname" value="first" />
</form>
<form class='item-card' name='second' action='reload.php' method = 'post' enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>
  <input type="hidden" name="formname" value="second" />
</form>
```

Comment: Забыл написать. Форм очень много и их name генерируется рандомно

Comment: @АндрейПовх В моем ответе это ничего не изменит.